# AWS S3 - Possible to automatically change storage class if files have not been accessed in X days?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know it's possible to set up a rule so that files created X days ago have their storage class set to Infrequent Access. What I'd like to do is set up S3 so that the following rules are in place:

- If a file has not been accessed/downloaded in X days, change its storage class from Standard to Infrequent Access
- If a file is accessed more than X times in Y days, change its storage class back to Standard

If point #2 is not possible, I'd be happy enough with just changing the storage class back to Standard even if the file is accessed once.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTlifecycle.html  I think you can do it by playing with all the options like NoncurrentVersionTransition alongwith NoncurrentDays

Comment: Noncurrent only deals with versioned files, nothing to do with when they were accessed, @abs